# How to convert results of an Oracle SQL query into columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

My query output is the below.

[image]

But I need the result to be in the below format.

[image]

Comment: Google for "pivot query SQL".

Comment: Use a sql client like squirrel that structure the results in good fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output can be achieved as follows -

**Setup:-**

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1
(
  ID NUMBER,
  ATTRNAME VARCHAR2(1024),
  ATTRVALUE VARCHAR2(1024)
);


insert into tab1 values (1, 'Name', 'Mark');
insert into tab1 values (1, 'Email', 'abc@cdf.com');
insert into tab1 values (1, 'Phone num', '12234');

insert into tab1 values (2, 'Name', 'Julie');
insert into tab1 values (2, 'Email', 'abc@cdf.com');
insert into tab1 values (2, 'Phone num', '12234');
```

**Query:-**

```
select * from (
  select * from tab1)
pivot(
  max(attrvalue) for attrname in ('Name', 'Email','Phone num')
  ) order by id;
```

**Result:-**

```
ID  'Name'  'Email' 'Phone num'
1   Mark    abc@cdf.com 12234
2   Julie   abc@cdf.com 12234
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by using the below query..

```
select ID,
MAX(DECODE(usr.attrname, 'NAME' , usr.ATTRVAL)) AS NAME,
MAX(DECODE(usr.attrname, 'EMAIL' , usr.ATTRVAL))  AS EMAIL,
MAX(DECODE(usr.attrname, 'Phonenum' , usr.ATTRVAL)) AS Phonenum
from usr
group by ID order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from employee
pivot (
max(attribute)  for your column in('NAME','EMAIL','Phone'));